# Crontab command not executed

Tags: linux, cron, mysqldump

I have a command in my crontab that doesn't execute correctly, this should backup the database everyday at the specified time. I tried running the command in my terminal and is working properly.

To edit my crontab I use `crontab -e` the current cron tab contains the following:

```
# Save online agent status every 2 minutes
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/dummy/scm/qt-savu/userstatus.py >> /home/dummy/qt-savu/userstatus.log

# Save Hourly call counts every XX:59
59 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/dummy/scm/qt-savu/hourlylog.py >> /home/dummy/qt-savu/hourlycc.log

# Backup albatross everyday
58 5 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -udummy -ppassword albatross | /bin/gzip > /home/dummy/Documents/backups/`/bin/date +%y.%m%d`.albatross.tar.gz

# Backup bert everyday
58 5 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -udummy -ppassword bert | /bin/gzip > /home/dummy/Documents/backups/`/bin/date +%y.%m%d`.bert.tar.gz
```

Other commands in the crontab are working properly, The commands that are not working are:

```
# Backup albatross everyday
58 5 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -udummy -ppassword albatross | /bin/gzip > /home/dummy/Documents/backups/`/bin/date +%y.%m%d`.albatross.tar.gz

# Backup bert everyday
58 5 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -udummy -ppassword bert | /bin/gzip > /home/dummy/Documents/backups/`/bin/date +%y.%m%d`.bert.tar.gz
```

The log output looks like this

```
Sep  4 05:56:01 luna CRON[18815]: (dummy) CMD (/usr/bin/mysqldump -udummy -ppassword bert | /bin/gzip > /home/dummy/Documents/backups/`/bin/date '+)
Sep  4 05:56:01 luna CRON[18812]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep  4 05:56:01 luna CRON[18817]: (dummy) CMD (/usr/bin/mysqldump -udummy -ppassword albatross | /bin/gzip > /home/dummy/Documents/backups/`/bin/date '+)
Sep  4 05:56:01 luna CRON[18813]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

As I observed the output of the log stops at `/bin/date`.

Comment: I would recommend you put you commands into a shell scripts and then call these to keep the crontab simple to read

Comment: thanks for the tip, doesn't it increase the complexity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%` is treated specially by cron. It is used to denote the end of the command portion and the beginning of standard input. As such, you must escape it, like so: `\%`.

From the crontab man page:

> The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the crontab file.

Comment: God sent, been troubled by this for more than an hour... is there a list of special chars in the man pages?

That explains the weird syntax highlighting - (edit)

Comment: Per the manpage (`man 5 crontab`), the sixth field only has that one special character.